# How to get Volume Serial Number using Visual Basic 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to get Volume Serial Number using Visual Basic 2010,

Is there a whole code example that shows me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: The Drive Volume Serial Number?

Comment: Yes, its the same when you type vol in windows cmd

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read HDD volume serial number using VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101857/how-can-i-read-hdd-volume-serial-number-using-vb-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the simplest answer to my question was given by:

Hans Passant:
From his link,

I just copied and pasted this function and it works for Microsoft Visual basic 2010 express, Without any modifications

```
Public Function GetDriveSerialNumber() As String
    Dim DriveSerial As Long
    Dim fso As Object, Drv As Object
    'Create a FileSystemObject object
    fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Drv = fso.GetDrive(fso.GetDriveName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory))
    With Drv
        If .IsReady Then
            DriveSerial = .SerialNumber
        Else    '"Drive Not Ready!"
            DriveSerial = -1
        End If
    End With
    'Clean up
    Drv = Nothing
    fso = Nothing
    GetDriveSerialNumber = Hex(DriveSerial)
End Function
```

I would like to thank everyone for their help,

And i apologize for repeating the question,
I did do a google search and a stackflow search,
But my search was"
"get hard drive serial number in visual basic 2010"

So this website did not show up,

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This thread here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43281cfa-51c8-4c35-bc31-929c67abd943/getting-drive-volume-serial-number-in-vb-2010 has the following bit of code that you could use/adapt.

> I made a piece of code for you to show all drive information.
>
> The Volume serial number is included you can get that by simple
>   putting some more if's in the code

```
Imports System.Management
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim drivetype() As String = {"Unknown", "NoRootDirectory", _
    "RemoveableDisk", "LocalDisk", "NetworkDrive", "CompactDisk", "RamDisk"}
    Dim allDrives() As String = Environment.GetLogicalDrives()
    For Each drive In allDrives
      Dim win32Drive As String = _
      "Win32_LogicalDisk='" & drive.Substring(0, 2) & "'"
      Dim Disk As System.Management.ManagementObject _
      = New System.Management.ManagementObject(win32Drive)
      Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(drive.ToString & drivetype(CInt((Disk("DriveType").ToString))))
      For Each diskProperty In Disk.Properties
        If Not diskProperty.Value Is Nothing Then
          Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("---" & diskProperty.Name & "=" & diskProperty.Value.ToString)
        End If
      Next
    Next
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Does this work on visual basic 2010?


I’m getting an error for System.Management.ManagementObject,

It says Type “System.Management.ManagementObject” is not defined!

Thanks

Comment: Microsoft Visual basic 2010 express

Comment: You have to add System.Management as a reference (see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314630/managementobject-class-not-showing-up-in-system-management-namespace)