# GetDriveSerialNumber() not working as intended on a specific computer, using visual basic 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using GetDriveSerialNumber() to retrieve drive volume serial number in visual basic 2010.

I have the following imports:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Collections
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
```

And then in the Module:

```
Dim path As String

   'Get HD volume Serial Number from Function
        Dim DriveVID As String = GetDriveSerialNumber()
```

The function is:

```
'Get HD Volume serial Number
Public Function GetDriveSerialNumber() As String
    Dim DriveSerial As Long
    Dim fso As Object, Drv As Object
    'Create a FileSystemObject object
    fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Drv = fso.GetDrive(fso.GetDriveName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory))
    With Drv
        If .IsReady Then
            DriveSerial = .SerialNumber
        Else    '"Drive Not Ready!"
            DriveSerial = -1
        End If
    End With
    'Clean up
    Drv = Nothing
    fso = Nothing
    GetDriveSerialNumber = Hex(DriveSerial)
End Function
```

This works great for 9 out 10 computers,

Only one gives me back a different 7 characters,

Oppose to the 8 characters it should give me,

Even when I type vol command in cmd,

On that computer,

It gives me the correct 8 characters volume serial number,

Does anyone know what’s wrong?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18618936/1840239) how GetDriveSerialNumber() is defined?  That info is required, too. :)

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add the function, i just did that.

Answer (score 0):

This Function seems to work with all my test computers:

```
Private Function GetDriveSerialNumber(ByVal drive As String) As String
    Dim driveSerial As String = String.Empty
    Dim driveFixed As String = Path.GetPathRoot(drive)

    driveFixed = Replace(driveFixed, "\", String.Empty)

    Using querySearch As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT VolumeSerialNumber FROM Win32_LogicalDisk Where Name = '" & driveFixed & "'")
        Using queryCollection As ManagementObjectCollection = querySearch.Get()
            Dim moItem As ManagementObject
            For Each moItem In queryCollection

                driveSerial = CStr(moItem.Item("VolumeSerialNumber"))

                Exit For
            Next
        End Using
    End Using

    Return driveSerial
End Function
```

The only thing is that you have to send a drive letter to the Function,
Which is not a problem with me,